# mercurial (hg) extension for Review Board 3

Tags: mercurial, review-board

I'm planning to upgrade reviewboard version 1.5 to 3.0.5. We are using postreview  extension on mercurial to update review on review board server which is 1.5 version. The existing is not working or deprecated for Review Board version 3.

I don't see any support for latest version. Please help on this.

Thanks in advance.